# What is the appropriate question tag for sentences such as “I was born to be a doctor”?

Tags: grammaticality

What is the appropriate question tag for sentences such as:

> I was born to be a doctor, **__**?

Answer (score 3):

Wasn't I?

You need to use the auxiliary verb in the original sentence, in this case 'was'. In a question tag you add 'not' to that auxiliary verb when the original sentence is positive. (Question tags are always the opposite).

Comment: That's the 'syntactically governed' answer, but pragmatics demands that care be taken in using it. It _could_ sound very smug. No such problem with the equivalent 'He was born to be a doctor, wasn't he?'

Comment: On that note @EdwinAshworth *I was born to be a doctor, but was he?*